# how to make a search form

Tags: views, 7, forms

I would like to make a search form for my site so that users can use a series of drop down menus and click to search and it will create a view with listings that fit the criteria of the search.

Its for a property/real-estate website so I want the user to be able to select how many bedrooms, price range, and location. Then, they will get a list or properties that are in the location  selected with the number of bedrooms specified etc.  I  spent a while searching and all I could find is how to customize a single Drupal search field in the header.

Answer (score 4):

You add some filter criteria, and expose them to the users who see the view. The filter criteria can be any of the filter criteria implemented by the Views module, but there is one that you are probably interested to add it for a search view: *Search: Search Terms.*

> [image: screenshot]

> [image: screenshot]

You could also add a filter for selecting the user who posted the node, and the date when the node was posted.

> [image: screenshot]

> [image: screenshot]

At the end, the view page would appear similar to the following one.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: oo thanks very much, thats what i was after, thanks for taking the time to reply to my question.

Comment: Oh there is one more thing, i think this method would have the filters on the views page right? this is still really helpful and may be the way i choose to o it, but id also like to know how i could have like a search form on my main page which then opened the views page, so sort of to apply these filters before hitting the search button.